# How show in foreach post of only parent category

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a script that creates tabs.
The parent categories are shown in the navigation tabs.
While the posts are shown in the content of the tabs.
I have a problem with the first foreach which should only print posts belonging to parent categories.
But in the third tab "Punti vendità" which should print only the posts of the subcategoories the 1st foreach prints the posts of the subcategories erroneously duplicating the posts.
Summary...
I have the first foresch that needs to print only .post-category cards for parent categories.
And the second foreach correctly prints the sub-category .post-sub-category cards.
How do you tell the first foreach to print only posts belonging to parent categories?
Thanks a lot for the help

[image]

`

```
<div data-parent="true" class="vc_row row-container" id="tab-category-distributori">
  <div class="row no-top-padding triple-bottom-padding tab-category-distributori single-h-padding limit-width row-parent" data-imgready="true">
    <div class="wpb_row row-inner">
      <div class="wpb_column pos-top pos-center align_left column_parent col-lg-12 single-internal-gutter">
        <div class="uncol style-light">
          <div class="uncoltable">
            <div class="uncell">
              <div class="uncont no-block-padding">
                <div class="uncode-tabs wpb_content_element border-100" data-interval="" data-target="row">
                  <div data-parent="true" class="vc_row row-container" id="tab-category-distributori">
                    <!-- start tab category -->
                    <div class="uncode-wrapper tab-container default-typography">

                      <?php
                      function ow_categories_with_subcategories_and_posts($taxonomy, $post_type) {

                        // pure CSS example https://codepen.io/maheshambure21/pen/VvxWYZ

                        function card_distributori() {
                          $foto_sede = get_field('foto_sede');
                          $ragione_sociale = get_field('ragione_sociale');
                          $indirizzo = get_field('indirizzo');
                          $telefono = get_field('telefono');
                          $fax = get_field('fax');
                          $cellulare = get_field('cellulare');
                          $e_mail = get_field('e-mail');
                          $sito_web = get_field('sito_web');

                          $labelTel = '';
                          $labelFax = '';
                          $labelCelulare = '';
                          $labelEmail = '';
                          $labelWeb = '';

                          if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ita') {
                            $labelTel = 'Tel';
                            $labelFax = 'Fax';
                            $labelCelulare = 'Mobile';
                            $labelEmail = 'E-mail';
                            $labelWeb = 'Sito web';
                          } elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'eng') {
                            $labelTel = 'Tel';
                            $labelFax = 'Fax';
                            $labelCelulare = 'Mobile';
                            $labelEmail = 'E-mail';
                            $labelWeb = 'Website';
                          } elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fra') {
                            $labelTel = 'Tel';
                            $labelFax = 'Fax';
                            $labelCelulare = 'Portable';
                            $labelEmail = 'E-mail';
                            $labelWeb = 'Site Internet';
                          } elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'deu') {
                            $labelTel = 'Tel';
                            $labelFax = 'Fax';
                            $labelCelulare = 'Mobile';
                            $labelEmail = 'E-mail';
                            $labelWeb = 'Webseite';
                          } elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'pol') {
                            $labelTel = 'Tel';
                            $labelFax = 'Faks';
                            $labelCelulare = 'Mobilny';
                            $labelEmail = 'E-mail';
                            $labelWeb = 'Stronie internetowej';
                          } elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'rus') {
                            $labelTel = 'тел';
                            $labelFax = 'Факс';
                            $labelCelulare = 'мобильный';
                            $labelEmail = 'Эл. почта';
                            $labelWeb = 'Веб-сайт';
                          } elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'zhs') {
                            $labelTel = '电话';
                            $labelFax = '传真';
                            $labelCelulare = '移动的';
                            $labelEmail = '电子邮件';
                            $labelWeb = '网站';
                          }

                          echo '<div class="post-category_card-distributori">';
                          if ($foto_sede) {
                            echo '<div class="image"><img src="' . $foto_sede . '"/></div>';
                          }
                          if ($ragione_sociale) {
                            echo '<h4 class="ragione-sociale">' . $ragione_sociale . '</h4>';
                          }
                          if ($indirizzo) {
                            echo '<div class="indirizzo">' . $indirizzo . '</div>';
                          }
                          if ($indirizzo) {
                            echo '<p class="telefono">' . $labelTel . ': ' . $telefono . '</p>';
                          }
                          if ($fax) {
                            echo '<p class="fax">' . $labelFax . ': ' . $fax . '</p>';
                          }
                          if ($cellulare) {
                            echo '<p class="cellulare">' . $labelCelulare . ': ' . $cellulare . '</p>';
                          }
                          if ($e_mail) {
                            echo '<p class="e_mail">' . $labelEmail . ':<br> <a href="' . $e_mail . '">' . $e_mail . '</a></p>';
                          }
                          if ($sito_web) {
                            echo '<p class="sito_web">' . $labelWeb . ':<br> <a href="' . $sito_web . '" target="_blank" rel="noopener">' . $sito_web . '</a></p>';
                          }
                          echo '</div><!-- end post-category_card-distributori -->';
                        };

                        // Get the top categories that belong to the provided taxonomy (the ones without parent)
                        $categories = get_terms(
                          array(
                            'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
                            'parent'     => 0, // <-- No Parent
                            'orderby'    => 'term_id',
                            'hide_empty' => true // <!-- change to false to also display empty ones
                          )
                        );

                        echo '<div class="category-class">';

                        echo '<div class="vc_tta-tabs-container">';
                        echo '<ul class="nav nav-tabs wpb_tabs_nav ui-tabs-nav vc_tta-tabs-list text-center">';

                        // Iterate through all categories to display each individual category
                        $countTab = 0;
                        foreach ($categories as $category) {

                          $cat_name = $category->name;
                          $cat_id   = $category->term_id;
                          $cat_slug = $category->slug;

                          $countTab++;

                          // Display the name of each individual category
                          // echo '<h3>Category: ' . $cat_name . ' - ID: ' . $cat_id . ' - Slug: ' . $cat_slug  . '</h3>';
                          // echo '<h3>Category: ' . $cat_name . '</h3>';

                          if ($countTab === 1) {
                            echo '<li data-tab-id="' . $cat_slug . '" data-tab-o-id="' . $countTab . '" class="vc_tta-tab  active ' . $countTab . '">
                                    <a href="#' . $cat_slug . '" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-history="true" data-tab-history-changer="push" data-tab-history-update-url="true"><span>' . $cat_name . '</span></a>
                                  </li>';
                          } elseif ($countTab > 1) {
                            echo '<li data-tab-id="' . $cat_slug . '" data-tab-o-id="' . $countTab . '" class="vc_tta-tab ' . $countTab . '">
                                      <a href="#' . $cat_slug . '" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-history="true" data-tab-history-changer="push" data-tab-history-update-url="true"><span>' . $cat_name . '</span></a>
                                    </li>';
                          }
                        }

                        echo '</ul><!-- // nav-tabs -->';
                        echo '</div><!-- end vc_tta-tabs-container  -->';

                        echo '<div class="tab-content wpb_wrapper">';

                        // Get the top categories that belong to the provided taxonomy (the ones without parent)
                        $categoriespost = get_terms(
                          array(
                            'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
                            'parent'     => 0, // <-- No Parent
                            'orderby'    => 'term_id',
                            'hide_empty' => true // <!-- change to false to also display empty ones
                          )
                        );

                        $countTabCont = 0;
                        foreach ($categoriespost as $category) {

                          $cat_name = $category->name;
                          $cat_id   = $category->term_id;
                          $cat_slug = $category->slug;

                          $countTabCont++;


                          
                          // Get all posts that belong to this specific subcategory
                          $postsCategory = new WP_Query(
                            array(
                              'post_type'      => $post_type,
                              'posts_per_page' => -1, // <-- Show all posts
                              'hide_empty'     => true,
                              'order'          => 'ASC',
                              'tax_query'      => array(
                                array(
                                  'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                  'field'    => 'term_id',
                                  'terms'    => $category->term_id,
                                )
                              )
                            )
                          );
                          // echo '<div class="tab-content">';
                          // open tab content
                          if ($countTabCont === 1) {
                            echo '<div data-id="' . $cat_slug . '" class="tab-pane tab-pane-distributori fade half-internal-gutter single-block-padding active in">
                                    <div>
                                      <div class="uncode_text_column">';
                          } elseif ($countTabCont > 1) {
                            echo '<div data-id="' . $cat_slug . '" class="tab-pane tab-pane-distributori fade half-internal-gutter single-block-padding">
                                    <div class"container-cards">
                                      <div class="uncode_text_column">';
                          }

                            // If there are posts available within this subcategory
                            // show post of all category but need show only post parent of category level 0
                            if ($postsCategory->have_posts()) {
                              echo '<div class="post-category">';

                              // se la categoria è òa 209 .. la salto perchè faccio vedere le sottocategorie
                              //if ($cat_id != 209){
                                    // As long as there are posts to show
                                  while ($postsCategory->have_posts()) : $postsCategory->the_post();
                                    card_distributori();
                                  endwhile;
                              //}

                              echo '</div><!-- end post-category -->';
                            } else {
                              echo '<div class="hide-post-nofound">No posts found</div>';
                            };

                                        // Get all the subcategories that belong to the current category
                                        $subcategories = get_terms(
                                          array(
                                            'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
                                            'parent'     => $cat_id, // <-- The parent is the current category
                                            'orderby'    => 'term_id',
                                            'hide_empty' => true
                                          )
                                        );

                                        echo '<div class="sub-category-class">';
                                        // Iterate through all subcategories to display each individual subcategory
                                        foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {

                                          $subcat_name = $subcategory->name;
                                          $subcat_id   = $subcategory->term_id;
                                          $subcat_slug = $subcategory->slug;

                                          // Display the name of each individual subcategory with ID and Slug
                                          // echo '<h4>Subcategory: ' . $subcat_name . ' - ID: ' . $subcat_id . ' - Slug: ' . $subcat_slug  . '</h4>';
                                          echo '<h4 class="sub-category-class_title">' . $subcat_name . '</h4>';

                                          // Get all posts that belong to this specific subcategory
                                          $postsSubcategory = new WP_Query(
                                            array(
                                              'post_type'      => $post_type,
                                              'posts_per_page' => -1, // <-- Show all posts
                                              'hide_empty'     => true,
                                              'order'          => 'ASC',
                                              'tax_query'      => array(
                                                array(
                                                  'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                                  'terms'    => $subcat_id,
                                                  'field'    => 'id'
                                                )
                                              )
                                            )
                                          );

                                          // If there are posts available within this subcategory
                                          if ($postsSubcategory->have_posts()) {
                                            echo '<div class="post-sub-category">';

                                            // As long as there are posts to show
                                            while ($postsSubcategory->have_posts()) : $postsSubcategory->the_post();
                                              card_distributori();
                                            endwhile;

                                            echo '</div><!-- end post-sub-category -->';

                                          } else {
                                            echo 'No posts found';
                                          };

                            wp_reset_query();
                          } // end foreach subcategory
                          echo '</div><!-- end sub-category-class -->';

                          // echo '</div><!-- tab-content -->';
                          // close tab content
                          echo      '</div><!-- // .uncode_text_column -->
                                  </div><!-- // .container-cards -->
                                </div><!-- // .tab-pane -->';
                        } // end foreach category
                        echo '</div><!-- end category-class -->';
                      } ow_categories_with_subcategories_and_posts('categoria-distributore', 'distributore');
                      ?>

                    </div><!-- close tab category -->


                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script id="script-tab-category-distributori" data-row="script-tab-category-distributori" type="text/javascript" class="vc_controls">
          UNCODE.initRow(document.getElementById("tab-category-distributori"));
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- fix full with under block -->
```

`

Comment: Why you are putting function in function any specific reason?

Comment: Because i want reuse design of card singol distributor

Comment: Hi there
how filter only post assigned of parent category in an array inside of foreach - foreach ($categories as $category) {array(} }? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting this parameter in the array
'include_children' => 0,

```
// Get all posts that belong to this specific subcategory
$postsCategory = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type'      => $post_type,
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // <-- Show all posts
    'hide_empty'     => true,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'tax_query'      => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => $category->term_id,
        'include_children' => 0,
      )
    )
  )
);
```